# How to convert x,y to longitude, latitude in Cesium?

Tags: javascript, cesium

Actually I have divided a line into 90 parts. I know the longitudes and latitudes of end points, and for rest of the intermediate points I know x and y. I have to find height for those 90 points and for that I need those points in proper format of longitude and latitude.

Otherwise, please suggest met another way to find n number of intermediate points between two given points. (latitudes and longitudes)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question but have you looked into the Cartesian2.fromElements method or some of the other Cartesian2 methods [here](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cartesian2.html)

Comment: @ChrisR Actually I have divided a line into 90 parts. I know the longitudes and latitudes of end points, and for rest of the intermediate points I know x and y. I have to find height for those 90 points and for that I need those points in proper format of longitude and latitude.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 
Ideally, questions should stand on their own, without comment.
Please **[edit]** the extra information, provided in comments, into the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand what the known X,Y values are, but if you have an start and end lat/long pair and you just want to break it into n segments there are a few different paths you can go depending on what your use case is.

Personally I would use the movable type's Lat/Lon library.

- Calculate the distance and bearing/heading.
- divide up the distance by the number of segments
- use movable to find each of the points given the bearing and incremental distance.